# XmlWriter.WriteNode() does not write tags for any Elements

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am working on a C#.NET program that is attempting to write the XML data

returned from SQL Server, that is to be accessed by an XmlReader

returned by the `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()` method.

The SqlCommand query text is "`SELECT ... FOR XML, ELEMENTS`".

The code copies the XML data from an XmlReader to an XmlWriter, 
by using the XmlWriter.WriteNode() method.

**BUT XmlWriter.WriteNode() does not write the start tag and end tag for any Elements;
It writes only the Text content for the Elements.**

Obviously my intention is to write the tags as well as the Text for the Elements.
I have included the code and the output from the SELECT Query and WriteNode() method.
below.

Does anybody have an explanation why XmlWriter.WriteNode() does not write the tags
and writes only the Text data?

**C#:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    XPathNavigator xPathNavigator = xmlDocument.CreateNavigator();

    string connectionStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;"
                                    +
                          "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
                                    +
                          "Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCommand
            = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1  ContactID, " +
                             "              Title, " +
                             "        FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, " +
                             "              Suffix, " +
                             "              EmailAddress, Phone "
                                    +
                             "  FROM Person.Contact AS Contact "
                                    +
                             "  FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS ",         
                             sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = xPathNavigator.PrependChild())
        {
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Contacts");

            using (XmlReader xmlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {

                xmlWriter.WriteNode(xmlReader,
                                    true);
            }    

            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }                  
    }        

    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    xmlDocument.Save(Response.Output);
}
```

Result set returned in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
<Contact>
  <ContactID>1</ContactID>
  <Title>Mr.</Title>
  <FirstName>Gustavo</FirstName>
  <LastName>Achong</LastName>
  <EmailAddress>gustavo0@adventure-works.com</EmailAddress>
  <Phone>398-555-0132</Phone>
</Contact>
```

.aspx output:

1 Mr. Gustavo Achong gustavo0@adventure-works.com 398-555-0132

Answer (score 0):

try returning the XML not as a SQL XML entity, but rather in a dataset as a string and then printing the string so the CDATA don't get stripped.